Not displaying contributions on the Github chart
For some time, my contributions have not been displayed on the Github chart now.
This is the second time this is happening; I have no idea how it got fixed the first time.
When this happens, my profile picture doesn't display on my commits like the picture below:

Here's the links to repos #1 and #2.
I just configured my email & username and pushed, my latest commit displayed, but not the ones before that one what do I do:


Show us browser Developer console. Are there any errors ?

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+count+contribution

Commits where GH show your profile picture and a link to the profile are Ok, they're counted. But commit without picture and link were created with wrong email(s). You need to rewrite history and change wrong email(s) to the one you use for this profile; then force-push.


my profile picture doesn't display on my commits.
...
my latest commit displayed, but not the ones before that one

Based on your description it seems it is a network (slow internet) error.
Is your internet connection slow ?
Try to open the page in different WiFi network.
If the page renders as expected then it confirms that your internet connection is slow.
You can either ignore this issue since it is the problem with slow internet or
change your profile photo to different photo with smaller size.

I did change my profile picture but nothing changed
